# Is it possible to have conditional variables on helm charts for deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, kubernetes-helm

Is it possible to have some sort of condition check before declaring a variable in a helm chart for deployment?

For example lets say I have

```
        - name: EXAMPLE_VAR
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: "name"
              key: "key"
```

but I only want to include this in my deployment for a specific configuration (based on lets say an environment variable) and don't want to have to maintain a seperate yaml configuration just for this configuration option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you have this in your chart's values.yaml

```
some-condition: true
```

Then in deployment template you may do like that:

```
spec:
  env:
  {{- if .Values.some-condition }}
  - name: EXAMPLE_VAR
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: "name"
        key: "key"
  {{- end }}
```

Comment: So I should be going through the values.yaml to be doing this? Got it, thanks!